# How to ArrayFormula in Google Sheets with multiple IF AND OR conditions?

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

Can someone please help me?
I can't get seems to work it.

What else should I do?

[image: Click here for picture]

Here is my code

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(AND(Y2:Y="VUL",L2:L="ANNUAL"),V2:V*0.03,IF(AND(Y2:Y="VUL",L2:L="QUARTERLY"),V2:V>0,IF(AND(Y2:Y="VUL",L2:L="SEMI ANNUAL"),V2:V*AB2:AB,"0"))))
```

The results must be from 2nd row to last but only works only for 2nd row.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75082108/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data with your manually entered desired results side-by-side. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ifs()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  ifs( 
    Y2:Y <> "vul", iferror(1/0),
    L2:L = "annual", V2:V * 0.03, 
    L2:L = "quarterly", V2:V > 0, 
    L2:L = "semi annual", V2:V * AB2:AB, 
    true, iferror(1/0) 
  ) 
)
```

Comment: it works but the problem here is some of the results were TRUE or FALSE

Comment: The formula above will give a true or false result when `L2:L = "quarterly"`, which is how your original formula appears to work. If you want a different result, modify the `V2:V > 0` bit as required. If you need more help, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75082108/edit) your question as requested in the comment to the question.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((Y2:Y="VUL")*(L2:L="ANNUAL"), V2:V*0.03,
 IF((Y2:Y="VUL")*(L2:L="QUARTERLY"), V2:V>0,
 IF((Y2:Y="VUL")*(L2:L="SEMI ANNUAL"), V2:V*AB2:AB, "0"))))
```

`AND` is `*`

`OR` is `+`

Comment: it works but the problem here is some of the results were TRUE or FALSE

Comment: @user20982250 `TRUE` `FALSE` comes from your `V2:V>0`

Answer (score 0):

Got the rights answer

thank you so much guys

```
    =ARRAYFORMULA(IF((Y2:Y="VUL")*(L2:L="ANNUAL"),V2:V*0.03,
 IF((Y2:Y="VUL")*(L2:L="QUARTERLY")*(V2:V>0), V2:V*AB2:AB,
 IF((Y2:Y="VUL")*(L2:L="SEMI ANNUAL")*(V2:V>0), V2:V*AB2:AB, "0"))))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).